# How to make css-animation of rotation around full circle

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have the element which rotate sometimes by `transform: rotate()`. I want to smooth transition between states by using `transition: transform`. The problem is that degrees in `rotate()` are hardcoded to be always between `-360` and `+360`, so after one full round degree's value jumps from `359` to `0` and animation does full circle back instead of smooth small animation to the right. Is there any way to make transition works "by the shortest way"?

*Update:* angle calculates from camera position so I can't use unlimited degrees value right now.

*Clarification:* I can't change js code right now, only CSS. So only `[0, 360)` degrees at this moment. Demo only simulates situation I'm in.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xvzme0q6/2/)**

```js
o = document.querySelector("#arrow");
t = document.querySelector("#text");
angle = 0;
delta = 2;
FULL_TURN = 360;

document.querySelector("html").addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  if (e.buttons === 1) {
    if (e.movementX > 0) {
      angle += delta;
    }
    if (e.movementX < 0) {
      angle -= delta;
    }
    angle %= FULL_TURN;
    o.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
    t.innerText = angle + "deg";
  }
})
```

```css
#arrow {
  font-size: 6em;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  transform-origin: 50% 60%;
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<header>Drag mouse left or right</header>
<span id="text">0deg</span>
<div id="arrow">↑</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just count the "rounds" and add 360 per round to your angle:

```
value = angle + rounds*360;
```

See this working example:

```js
o = document.querySelector("#arrow");
t = document.querySelector("#text");
angle = 0;
delta = 2;
FULL_TURN = 360;
rounds = 0;

document.querySelector("html").addEventListener("mousemove", (e)=>{
 if (e.buttons === 1) {
    if (e.movementX > 0) {
       angle += delta;
       if (angle >= 360) rounds++;
    }
    if (e.movementX < 0) {
       angle -= delta;
       if (angle <= -360) rounds--;
    }
    angle %= FULL_TURN;
    value = angle + rounds*360;
    o.style.transform = "rotate(" + value + "deg)";
    t.innerText = angle + "deg";
  }
})
```

```css
#arrow {
  font-size: 10em;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  transform-origin: 50% 60%;
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
}
header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>Drag mouse left or right</header>
<span id="text">0deg</span>
<div id="arrow">↑</div>
```

Comment: Angle calculate from camera position so I can't use unlimited degrees value right now, on the demo I just simulated it. I can't change camera code for now.
I've updated the question.

Comment: I see you really wants to help and doing your best, but the problem is that I can't change js code at this moment, only css.