# How to make a pure-CSS animation of CLOCKWISE rotation past 359 degrees

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, css-animations, css-transitions

I'm having an issue with pure CSS-based rotation using `transform: rotate()` coupled with `transition: transform`.

When rotating past 360 degrees, the transition causes a counter-clockwise rotation. See code below or on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/russellthackston/pen/QWmyBwY).

I know I can just keep increasing/decreasing the degree value (e.g. 356->360, instead for 359->0), but this is for a React app and I'd like to simply use defined "states" with related CSS classes (i.e. class "over-1" equals the three o'clock position, "over-2" equals six o'clock, etc.).

I thought about storing the rotation value in the React state and increasing/decreasing it based on the triggering events, but I would need to inject that style directly into the HTML. Additionally, the elements I'm transforming have more than just angle being applied. I would need to also code those values in the JavaScript (e.g. `transform: "translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(" + this.state.rotation + "deg);"`) or else setting the transform property would overwrite the transform from the stylesheet (I think).

Also, I hate hardcoding style information in JavaScript.

I tried using a "transitional" process ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/russellthackston/pen/VwXeBjz)) that (1) used a class to animate the rotation from 270 to 360 degrees, (2) wait until the animation finished, then (3) switch the rotation from 360 degrees to 0 degrees (without animation), then (4) set the "correct" class to 0 degrees with the transition property (so it wouldn't be a one-off class assignment). The problem I had with this is that clicking the rotate button before the animation completed would interrupt the transition and show counter-clockwise rotation.

I found two other questions that were loosely related, but did not provide any answers.

- [How to make css-animation of rotation around full circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527888/how-to-make-css-animation-of-rotation-around-full-circle)
- [CSS rotation animation issue: creating a smooth transition from 270 degrees to -90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66929024/css-rotation-animation-issue-creating-a-smooth-transition-from-270-degrees-to)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            /* Button to trigger rotation */
            #control {
                position: absolute;
                top: 210px;
                left: 100px;
                transform: translate(-50%, 0)
            }
            /* Large, underlying disk */
            #under {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                background-color: blue;
                height: 200px;
                width: 200px;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
            /* Smaller, rotating disk */
            #over {
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                left: 100px;
                background-color: green;
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
                z-index: 1;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
            /* Simple pointer to visually track rotation */
            #pointer {
                font-size: 50px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
            /* Rotate inner disk to point to the twelve o'clock position */
            .over-1 {
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
                transition: transform 0.5s;
            }
            /* Rotate inner disk to point to the three o'clock position */
            .over-2 {
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
                transition: transform 0.5s;
            }
            /* Rotate inner disk to point to the six o'clock position */
            .over-3 {
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
                transition: transform 0.5s;
            }
            /* Rotate inner disk to point to the nine o'clock position */
            .over-4 {
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(270deg);
                transition: transform 0.5s;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            this.position = 1;
            /* Rotate the disk clockwise to the next position */
            function rotate() {
                this.position += 1;
                if (this.position === 2) {
                    document.getElementById("over").classList.remove("over-1");
                    document.getElementById("over").classList.add("over-2");
                }
                if (this.position === 3) {
                    document.getElementById("over").classList.remove("over-2");
                    document.getElementById("over").classList.add("over-3");
                }
                if (this.position === 4) {
                    document.getElementById("over").classList.remove("over-3");
                    document.getElementById("over").classList.add("over-4");
                }
                /* PROBLEM: The transition from nine o'clock to twleve o'clock
                            causes the disk to rotate 270 degrees COUNTER CLOCKWISE */
                if (this.position === 5) {
                    document.getElementById("over").classList.remove("over-4");
                    document.getElementById("over").classList.add("over-1");
                    this.position = 1;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="under"></div>
        <div id="over" class="over-1">
            <div id="pointer">^</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="control" onclick="rotate()">Rotate</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `0deg` is 270 degrees counterclockwise from `270deg`. `360deg` is 90 degrees clockwise from `270deg`.

Comment: @Amadan I not sure what to make of your comment. What are you suggesting?

Comment: That you should have a fifth class where the rotation is `360deg`.

Comment: @Amadan But how will that make a clean animation when I keep going and move from 360 to 90?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, to keep the rotation clockwise, you have to keep increasing the degrees. Thus, this is much easier to do directly in JavaScript rather than with classes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            /* Button to trigger rotation */
            #control {
                position: absolute;
                top: 210px;
                left: 100px;
                transform: translate(-50%, 0)
            }
            /* Large, underlying disk */
            #under {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                background-color: blue;
                height: 200px;
                width: 200px;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
            /* Smaller, rotating disk */
            #over {
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                left: 100px;
                background-color: green;
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
                z-index: 1;
                border-radius: 50%;
                
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
                transition: transform 0.5s;
            }
            /* Simple pointer to visually track rotation */
            #pointer {
                font-size: 50px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="under"></div>
        <div id="over">
            <div id="pointer">^</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="control">Rotate</button>
        </div>
        <script>
            window.rotation = 0;
            /* Rotate the disk clockwise to the next position */
            document.getElementById("control").addEventListener('click', evt => {
                window.rotation += 90;
                document.getElementById("over").style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(${this.rotation}deg)`;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want to do it with classes, you'd have to have a fifth class with `360deg` and separate `transition` into a different class. When you reach `360deg`, turn off the `transition`, switch to `0deg`, and turn transition back on, so it seamlessly resets without it being seen by the user.